# Ruby - how to find a combination of results from picking 1 value from each array of a list of arrays

Tags: ruby

Lets say i have the following arrays in ruby contained in an array and I don't know how many arrays there will be or the length of them. An example below:

```
[["cat", "dog"],[1, 3, 5, 7],["morning", "afternoon", "evening"]]
```

what i want to do is have all combinations of results from picking 1 value from each array and returning it as an array of these combinations. Therefore, in the following example, there should be 2*4*3, or 24 possible unique results.

the result would be like :

```
result = [["cat", 1, "morning"], ["cat", 1, "afternoon"], ["dog", 5, "evening"] ...]
```

How would i go about doing this in ruby for a list of N arrays? I tried messing around with products and maps and injects but I cant get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** Since you made it clear that you're dealing with not just three arrays `a1`, `a2` and `a3` but an arrays of arrays, changing my solution to use `product`.

<s>Like this?</s>

```
 a1.map{|x1| a2.map{|x2| a3.map{|x3| [x1, x2, x3] }}}.flatten(2)
```

Or with `flat_map`:

```
 a1.flat_map{|x1| a2.flat_map{|x2| a3.map{|x3| [x1, x2, x3] }}}
```

Wow, or just:

```
 a1.product(a2,a3)
```

If you have several arrays (not just the fixed number of 3 in you first example),
then:

```
 input = [["cat", "dog"],[1, 3, 5, 7],["morning", "afternoon", "evening"]]
 h,*rest = input
 result = h.product(*rest)
```

Comment: I rephrased the question because i actually don't know how many arrays I will have, so it may be 3, it may be 10. I need some way to dynamically do it without knowing the amount of arrays i have.

Comment: OK, so what would you consider as desirable the output for `[[1,2,3], [4,5]]`

Comment: [[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5],[3,4],[3,5]] the order of the arrays inside doesn't matter.

your edited answer looks correct. thanks!

Comment: @nicooga This isn't reddit, that kind of comment is why we have the ability to flag comments as "not constructive/off topic". Please don't post that crap here.

Answer (score 3):

[Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
xs[0].product(*xs.drop(1))
```

Note that you'd rather like to write `Array.product(*xs)`, but Ruby has no such classmethod in the core (easy to write, sure, but probably it should be there).

Comment: Or even, `xs.first.product(*xs.drop(1))`